# Smartparens: do not insert parenthesis pair when point is at the beginning of word

Tags: smartparens

How can I make `smartparens` *not* to insert a parenthesis pair when the point is at the beginning of a word? I only want it to insert the opening parenthesis.

This is my setup:

```
(use-package smartparens-config
  :ensure smartparens
  :diminish smartparens-mode
  :config
  (progn
    (smartparens-global-mode 1)
    (show-smartparens-global-mode 1)
    (setq
       smartparens-strict-mode nil
       sp-autoinsert-if-followed-by-word nil
       sp-autoskip-closing-pair 'always
       sp-base-key-bindings 'paredit
       sp-hybrid-kill-entire-symbol nil)
    ))
```

As you see, I have set `sp-autoinsert-if-followed-by-word` to `nil`, as the documentation recommends, but to no avail.

See the animated gif here:

[image: animated gif of problem]

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: `electric-pair-mode` behaves the way you want -- if you don't have to use `smartparens` for other reasons.

Answer (score 6):

[According](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/issues/645#issuecomment-245535672) to the author of smartparens, `sp-autoinsert-if-followed-by-word` has been deprecated. 
Instead, one should use the `:when` and `:unless` filters to accomplish what I wanted. (See the [documentation](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Permissions).)

Thus, the way I managed smartparens to work as I wanted was this:

```
(sp-pair "(" nil :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
(sp-pair "[" nil :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
(sp-pair "{" nil :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
(sp-local-pair 'latex-mode "$" nil :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
```

Answer (score 2):

Type C-q ( to only insert a single opening paren.

Comment: He wants the behaviour to be automatic. You may as well open a pair and press delete if using this solution.